# Быстрый запрос к серверу

Tags: php

Какой из запросов к серверу, можно считать самым быстрым.

Curl или сокет или...

Comment: *ICMP*? :-)

Comment: Раскажите о целях и задачах, которые вы решаете, а то ответ будет таким же...

Comment: Подключится к серверу, спарсить данные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для IP-запросов наиболее быстрым будет использование socket_create с параметром SOCK_RAW и применением ICMP-протокола.